# Can not compile jsp file in mvc model

Tags: java, mysql, xml, jsp, netbeans

My teacher gave me solution for a small project of a web application (Courses Registration) using MVC, `jsp pages` and 1 `controller` to connect to `MySQL` database. When I run each jsp it displays the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PWC6311: compilerTargetVM 1.8 too high
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.setCompilerTargetVM(JspC.java:700)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspC.main(JspC.java:76)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.project.ant.JspCSingle.main(JspCSingle.java:119)
    C:\Users\SONY\Downloads\New folder (2)\CourseReg\nbproject\build-impl.xml:936: Java returned: 1
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

When run the Controller-> a message :

> class Controller neither has main method nor is it a servlet
>   specified in web.xml.

But my teacher can run this without any web.xml file and no errors. I think there's something wrong with my Netbeans. Can you please help?

Comment: Format your question please...

Comment: Mr. dudedude, please check out some java tutorials, learn how to program and run java web application. You  seem to have no clue about running the web-app.

Comment: Where it says `compilerTargetVM 1.8 too high` (the first line of your error message), it means you have are compiling Java 8, but something else is expecting a lower version of Java.  You'll have to look at your project configuration to figure out what that is though.